# My function returns None although i have a return statement with a specific value

Tags: python

its my first year in my CS course and so some help will be appreciated. I try to make the Euclidian algorithm, and while it goes just fine, at the end it doesnt return the GCD (5) but None

```
def eykl(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return x
    elif x > y:
        l = x - y
        x = y
        print(f"{l}, {x}")
        eykl(l, x)
    else:
        l = y - x
        y = x
        print(f"{l}, {y}")
        eykl(l, y)
print(eykl(255, 155))
```

Comment: You must return `eykl(l, y)` and `eykl(l, x)`

Comment: You miss the return before you call  eykl using recursion

Comment: There is only one return in the `if` clause. If you go to the `elif` or `else` part of your code the is no return.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *return* the *recursive* results.

```
def eykl(x, y):
   if x == y:
       return x
   elif x > y:
       l = x - y
       x = y
       return eykl(l, x)
       ^^^^^^^^
   else:
       l = y - x
       y = x
       return eykl(l, y)
       ^^^^^^^
   print(eykl(255, 155))
```

Comment: Ah i see, Thank you!